# Deserializar cadena Json a clase Visual Basic

Tags: json, vba

He  tenido problemas para crear una clase como para esta cadena JSON. Les pido su ayuda con esta serialización y deserialización de JSON porque he buscado pero aun me sale error al deserializar.

JSON:

```
{
    "Local": "1",
    "CodProceso": "0000",
    "CodInterno": "1800000053",
    "CodExterno": "",
    "Mensaje": "Creado Correctamente",
    "ProductosErrados": ["", "", "", ""]
}
```

Clase para JSON:

```
public Class mijson
    Public Local As String
    Public CodProceso As String
    Public CodInterno As String
    Public CodExterno As String
    Public Mensaje As String
    Public ProductosErrados() As String
end Class
```

No sé si `ProductosErrados` está bien declarado pues el error no es específico.

Aquí es donde me salta el error:

```
dim rpta miclasejson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of miclasejson)(strRes)
```

Comment: Cual es el error?

Comment: Hola jimmy cusi, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y así ganar tu primera medalla). Esta pregunta es interesante, pero parece que le falta algo de información: ¿cuál es el mensaje de error que recibes? Y además, ¿podrías añadir algo más de contexto? Parece que el JSON lo tienes en un String que pasas a la clase para serializar/deserializar, pero sería ideal que añadieras más de tu código para que podamos probarlo y ayudarte con el problema. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' en Newtonsoft.Json.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario

Información adicional: Error converting value "{"Local":"1","CodProceso":"0000","CodInterno":"1800000072","CodExterno":"","Mensaje":"Creado Correctamente","ProductosErrados":[""]}" to type 'mijson'. Path '', line 1, position 158.

Comment: Hola alanfcm disculpa por responder recien

Comment: queria añadir esto muy importante: la cadena que recibo esta:  "{\"Local\":\"1\",\"CodProceso\":\"0000\",\"CodInterno\":\"1800000122\",\"CodExterno\":\"\",\"Mensaje\":\"Creado Correctamente\",\"ProductosErrados\":[\"\"]}"      entonces la idea es convertirla a un json y luego pasar a una clase Visual Basic.

Comment: aunque resolví el problema hace tiempo les comento como lo hice.     Dim rptaJson As JToken  
         rptaJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JToken)(strRes)

Comment: para despues hacer esto:                                                                                Dim rpta As BeanInforestRespuestaSA
rpta = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of BeanInforestRespuestaSA)(rptaJson)